# Codedom at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, codedom, class-diagram

I am building a code generation tool using vs 2010 visualisation & modelling sdk.  One of the things that I need to generate is a simple data capture ui (windows forms, preferably using devexpress layout control), with capture fields & labels for each property in a class.

I can use t4 text templates to do this, but I am conscious that I will be re-inventing the wheel if I do this - a simpler approach would be to add controls to a form constructed at runtime and allow the appropriate codedomseriaizer to generate the form.designer.cs code for me - is this possible?

To summarise, I would like to build a form at runtime, and retrieve a string of the designer.cs file..

Graham

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply leave the runtime generation code in use, and design only the other parts of the form using the designer? This way the autogenerated controls will be automatically updated if new properties are added to the class.

Comment: Yes, but I want the developer to be able to see & cutomise the form at design-time once the code generation has finished.